# Keeping a DIV at bottom-center of its parent DIV

Tags: css, html

My HTML structure is basically this -

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Ignore any elements except `<div id="header">`
I want to align `<div class="container">` inside `<div id="header">` at exactly bottom center. I'm using the following CSS code-

```
#header{ width:1062px; height:326px; background-color:#110000; text-align:center; position:relative; }
#header .container{ width:940px; height:262px; background-color:#220000; margin:0px auto; position:absolute; bottom:0px; }
```

There are height differences between the parent (#header) and child (#header .container) DIVs. Removing `position:absolute;` from the child centers it but it sticks to the parent's top instead of bottom.  Keeping `position:absolute;` sticks it at the bottom but aligns it to the left.

How do I align it both **center** AND **bottom** at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try in this way:

```
#header .container{ 
   width: 940px;  
   height: 262px; 
   background-color: #220000; 
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0 ;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -470px; 
}
```

Comment: This works. But apparently if I change the width of the .container, it's no longer center. Not that I need to change it right away, but are there any solution for the dynamic width situation?

Comment: if your element is in absolute you cannot control the alignment with margin: 0 auto; that's why you need to use this technique

Answer (score 27):

I tried all the solution above but it didn't work when you resize the browser window. This solution is mostly to be applied when you don't know the element's width. Or if the width is changed on resize.

After making some research I tried the following and it worked perfectly on all screen sizes.

```
#somelement {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

I shared this for anyone still facing this issue.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more! Worked perfectly on my setup!

Comment: This is a good approach. The only setback is that the width of #someelement will be restricted to 50% the width of the parent.

Comment: @clayRay No, this doesn't affect the with of the element. It only affects the positioning inside its parent. The width will remain as defined.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#header .container {
    width: 940px;
    height: 262px;
    background-color: #220000;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 61px;
}
```

Comment: This one works too but is no different from Fabrizio's answer: If the parent's/child's dimentions change, the .container is no longer center. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
#header{ 
width:1062px; height:262px; background-color:#110000; text-align:center;  
position:relative;text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom;padding-top:64px;
}  

#header .container{ 
    width:940px; 
    height:262px; 
    background-color:#999000; 
    margin:0px auto;
    bottom:0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/377Qh/)

**UPDATE:**
As DenisVuyka said in comment, i should add that the above sample was as answer to this particular question with fixed height for DIV.
If you want that height of DIV don't break up things then for example you should use `padding-top:10%;` in the `#header` and `height:100%` in `#header .container` CSS.

```
#header{ 
width:462px; height:262px; background-color:#110000; text-align:center;  
position:relative;text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom;padding-top:10%;  
}    

#header .container{ 
    width:300px; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:#999000; 
    margin:0px auto;
    bottom:0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d6ct6/ .

Comment: Sample does not work as expected. Try increasing #header height by 100 px and .container will be at the middle. It seems to be pinned to top only visually (by means of 'padding-top:64px' setting).

Comment: @DenisVuyka thanks for your comment. yes but no! That sample was as answer to that particular question with fixed height for DIV. if you want that height of DIV don't break up things then you should use percentage for `padding-top` in the `#header` and `height:100%` in `#header .container` CSS. here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d6ct6/ .

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get this to work in my project as well. I've edited this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d6ct6/

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

#header { 
height:100vh; 
background-color:#110000; 
position:relative; 
}
#header .container{ 
width:300px; 
height:40px; 
background-color:#999000; 
bottom:0px; 
position:absolute;
left:calc((100% - 300px)/2);
}
```

But I've found this only works when the width of .container is fixed.

If the width of .container is not fixed you would need javascript to find it's width and then change that width in the calc.

When the widths are responsive, use this:
HTML

```
<div id="header">
<div id="container">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header { 
height:100vh; 
background-color:#110000; 
position:relative; 
}
#container{ 
width:300px; 
height:40px; 
background-color:#999000; 
bottom:0px; 
position:absolute;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var parentWidth = $('#header').width();
var trapWidth = $('#container').width();
var deadCenter = (parentWidth - trapWidth);
var deadHalf = Number( deadCenter / 2 );
$('#container').css("right", deadHalf);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you care more about having the inside div aligned in the center and can manually set the vertical alignment.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ehitif/1/edit)  Height I used was first div height - second div height.

```
#header .container{ width:940px; height:262px; background-color:red; margin:0 auto; position:relative; top: 64px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take advantage of CSS table display properties and do the following:

```css
#header {
    width:1062px;
    height:326px;
    background-color:#110000;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#header .container {
    width:900px;
    height:262px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Set the `#header` block to `display: table-cell` and set `vertical-align: bottom` to align the child's bottom edge to the bottom edge of the parent.

The child `.container` element had `display: inline-block` and this will allow it to respond the `text-align: center` property of the parent.

This will work regardless of the width of the child `.container`.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/p9CxE/

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was bedevilling me for an hour or so, until I realised I could add an intermediary div; this separated the vertical alignment issue from the centering.

```css
.dparent {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}
.dchild {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.dmid {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
```

```html
    <div class="dparent">
        <div class="dmid">
            <div class="dchild"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Do the vertical alignment first, with an absolute position and the 0 bottom. Then do the centering with margin-left and margin-right set to auto.

Answer (score -2):

You might try this solution for any concerned width:

```
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom: 5px; 
left:50%;
margin-left:-50%;
```

Good luck!